# Does going through administrative process after postdoc interviews mean I received an unofficial offer?

Tags: postdocs

I am a recent PhD graduate and I had three rounds of interviews with the PI and other lab members over two weeks. The PI told me that I am moving to the administrative process and his staff would reach out to me soon. It has been a week since then, and I would like to know does going through the administrative process mean I have been selected for this position. If not, I would also like to know what administrative works are about and what would be a reasonable timeframe to follow up.

Thank you!

Comment: I think you should ask the PI; the administrative process at every institution can be different, it could be a mere formality or it could be effectively an insurmountable obstacle, we can't know.

Comment: Agree with the comment above. It seems that you probably have been selected. Was that an advertised position or did you contact the PI yourself to ask for an opening? Also have you send official transcripts to them?

Comment: @can'tstopmenow Thank you for the advice. It was posted on the official website of the university, I though't it may be impolite or impatient to ask the PI directly about whether I have been selected as the finalist. I wasn't requested for the official transcripts yet, earlier this week I followed up shortly and he told me he woudl check on the status with his staff and I told him I would await further communication from his staff. Would it be reasonable to reach out to him to ask for a status early in the next week?

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you for your advice. One more question...would it be inappropriate to ask the PI about where my application stands, such that whether I've been selected or the "administrative process" is another part before the selection?

Comment: @Serena Yes absolutely! Contact them and ask them. If it was already an announced position, then they don't need to announce it to hire you, so most probably they meant that they are moving the process to hire you. However then I they should have asked you for documents and transcripts, so there may be sth special in this case that has to be arranged.

Comment: @can'tstopmenow Thank you so much for the advice. I am trying to get patient with the slow process in academia but it's never easy....please wish me luck!!

Comment: @Serena Certainly communication styles vary culturally; I suspect from some of your wording you may come from a more indirect style, I don't know what the style is of the PI. However, I think for these sorts of things specifically, a more direct style is helpful. Ask *what exactly you need to know*, rather than hoping the other party will just fill in the details. Have I been selected, what steps need to be completed, approximately when will there be a final offer made - these are all very reasonable questions to ask.

Comment: @BryanKrause Thank you so much for the advice! Will include these questions to my next follow-up email..and hopefully I hear back before that happens... please wish me luck! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The PI will know what it means. However, the PI might not be allowed to tell you for a number of reasons.

For instance, your eligibility for the job needs to be determined or the final decision lies with a dean or provost. It could also be that the PI needs to get approval from the Grants office to ensure that there is funding for you.

In conclusion: While you most likely got the job, it is not a sure thing.